# How to change a variable string in scripts/modules when using ExtUtils::MakeMaker

Tags: linux, perl, makefile

I have some modules and scripts in an application written in perl. For its distribution I am using `ExtUtils::MakeMaker`.

The modules and scripts' target OS is Linux. The point is than I expect the final users will install the modules/scripts in non standard directories and maybe in their own directory, then they install like:

```
perl Makefile.PL PREFIX='/YOUR/DIRECTORY'
make
make test
make install
```

`ExtUtils::MakeMaker` solves the problem when the modules/scritps instalation directory are not standard and by `PREFIX` variable.

How can I copy or replace the `PREFIX` string' value into the scripts? for example, instead of hard code:

```
use lib '/YOUR/DIRECTORY';
```

I would like to replace it for a template like:

```
use lib '%%PREFIX%%';
```

where `%%PREFIX%%` is replaced in "compiling" time, and without set an environment variable (`$ENV{'PREFIX'}`)

Thank for your answers!!

Answer (score 2):

The thing to use is the PM_FILTER:

```
if (!($^O eq 'MSWin32' || $Config{'ccflags'} =~ /-D_?WIN32_?/)) {
    # doesn't work on windows: no sed
    $opts{'PM_FILTER'} = 'sed -e "s|/usr/share|$(PREFIX)/share|"';
}
```

Which works on linux and pretty much everything but windows (as you can see by the comments).

**[Updated to include more usage detail:]**

```
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;

%opts = (
     'NAME'         => 'myModulesAndScripts',
     # ...
    );

if (!($^O eq 'MSWin32' || $Config{'ccflags'} =~ /-D_?WIN32_?/)) {
    # doesn't work on windows: no sed
    $opts{'PM_FILTER'} = 'sed -e "s|/usr/share|$(PREFIX)/share|"';
}

WriteMakefile(%opts);
```

(and as is pointed out the comments, you can try to call perl itself in the PM_FILTER so you don't need the windows check; in my example above, however, I found instances where perl wasn't in the exec path and the existing PREFIX path of /usr was already ok...  You *can* define the PM_FILTER directly in the normal WriteMakefile argument list if you want.

Comment: For greater portability: `'perl -pe "s|/usr/share|$(PREFIX)/share|"'`

Comment: thank @Wes, I don't fully understand .. is the `PM_FILTER` from the [`Module::Build`](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Module-Build-0.3800/lib/Module/Build.pm)?

Comment: Sorry.  You can put that directly inside WriteMakefile opts.  I'll update it a bit.